# Create columns from another column which is a list of items

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say that I have a `DataFrame` with column `A` which is a list of strings of the form "Type:Value" where `Type` can have 5 different values and `Value` can be anything. What I would like to do is to create new 5 columns (each having appropriate `Type` name) where the value in each column would be the list of items which has a given `Type`. So if I have (1 row for simplicity):

```
df = pd.DataFrame("A": [["Type1:Value1", "Type2:Value2", "Type1:Value3"]])
```

then the result should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame("Type1": [["Value1", "Value3"]], "Type2":[["Value2"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Goes without saying, but there is a probably a better way to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [["Type1:Value1", "Type2:Value2", "Type1:Value3"]]})

buffer_dict = {}  # placeholder dict
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for str_value in row['A']:
        str_list = str_value.split(':')
        key = str_list[0]  # these are just for readability
        value = str_list[1]
        buffer_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)  # set default to list and append values
buffer_dict.update((k, [v]) for k, v in buffer_dict.items())  # enclose values in list so we can convert to df
result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(buffer_dict)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
              Type1     Type2
0  [Value1, Value3]  [Value2]
```

EDIT: I missed the part where there can only be 5 types. My solution was assuming this was unknown and will work for any amount of types.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution. This can be done on loop as well. But since the number of columns were small, the code is less automated.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [["Type1:Value1", "Type2:Value2", "Type1:Value3"]]})

    df[['x','y','z']] = df.A[0]
    
    df['type1'] = df.x.str.split(':').str[1]
df['type2'] = "[" +"[" + df.x.str.split(':').str[1]+ "]"
df['type1'] = "[" +"[" + df['type1'] +","+ df.x.str.split(':').str[1] + "]"+ "]"


print(df.drop(['A','x','y','z'], axis = 'columns'))



         type1      type2
0  [[Value1,Value1]]  [[Value1]
```

Comment: This may work for the exact dataset in the question, but the presumption is that this isn't the real dataset. Your solution doesn't take into account the 5 possible data types, only type1 accounts for multiple values, and the final df is not formatted the way it was requested in the question. In fairness I don't think my solution is perfect either lol.